# How to change the color of itemized text using `\color<>[]{}` in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, color, itemize, overlays

I want to change the item text color in Beamer.
I checked the [Beamer User Guide](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) and found the `\color<>[]{}` command in page 80.

> \color<2-3>[rgb]{1,0,0} This text is red on slides 2 and 3, otherwise black.

Then I found an example which uses this command in the `enumerate` environment [in the tutorial (page 15)](http://web.mit.edu/rsi/www/pdfs/beamer-tutorial.pdf).

```
\begin{enumerate}[A]   
    \item<2-5> James Madison    
    \item<3-5> Harry Truman    
    \item<4-> \color<6>[rgb]{0,0.6,0}Abraham Lincoln    
    \item<5-5> Calvin Coolidge    
\end{enumerate}
```

I then try a minimal example as follows (the example is also publicly available at [ShareLatex](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/529c69b0befa88390b004bdd). It is read-write allowed. So you are free to modify it.):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}   
\begin{document}    
    \begin{frame}    
        \begin{itemize}    
            \item \color<2>[rgb]{1,0,1}{text1}    
            \begin{itemize}    
                \item text11    
            \end{itemize}    
            \item text2    
            \begin{itemize}    
                \item text21    
            \end{itemize}    
            \item text3    
       \end{itemize}    
  \end{frame}  
\end{document}
```

On the first slide, it is OK:

[image: item text color 1]

On the second slide (`\color<2>[rgb]{1,0,1}{text1}`), all the three outer itemized texts (i.e., text1, text2, and text3) become red as shown in the following image. However, I only want to change the color of the first itemized text (i.e., text1 here).
[image: item text color 2]

Therefore, my question is:

> 1. How to change the color of a single itemized text (i.e., text1 here) using the command `\color<>[]{}`?
> 2. If the command is not feasible (why?), then what are the alternative approaches?

Comment: Use `\begin{itemize}[<+->]`

Comment: @Sigur: I believe it's just matter of grouping the text, i.e. putting braces: `\item {\color<2>[rgb]{1,0,1}{text1}}`.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino, yes, it works. We don't know it the OP wants to display all items at the same time. Thanks.

Comment: @Sigur It works _partially_. However, I don't want too many overlays introduced by `[<+->]`.

Comment: In alternative to grouping you can also use `\textcolor` which colors the text in its argument to confine the effect to it

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino It works. Thanks. Do you want to write your comment as an answer? Then, I can accept it.

Comment: @Bordaigorl Yes, it works too.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you call a `\color<overlay>[colorsys]{color}` command that changes the color *from then on* (within the current group) as it takes as argument only the color specification and not the content that needs to be colored.
What happens here is that the sub-itemizes are in their own color environment so they are not affected by your command; instead the other items are in the same color environment.
A simple example to illustrate the issue:

```
a {\color{red} a {\color{blue} a} a} a
```

[image: color]

To confine the effect of the `\color` macro then you can enclose it into a group

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}   
\begin{document}    
    \begin{frame}    
        \begin{itemize}    
            \item {\color<2>[rgb]{1,0,1} text1}    
            \begin{itemize}    
                \item text11    
            \end{itemize}    
            \item text2    
            \begin{itemize}    
                \item text21    
            \end{itemize}    
            \item text3    
       \end{itemize}    
  \end{frame}  
\end{document}
```

You can also use the `\textcolor<overlay>[colorsys]{color}{content}` macro which applies the change in color only to the content argument.

`\textcolor` is to `\color` what `\textbf` is to `\bf`.

Comment: +1, but I disagree with "[...] command that changes the color from then on"; as you said later, the color is applied to the current group, "from then on" seem to me pretty much the same as "for the rest of the document".

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino maybe this is more accurate now?

Comment: Excellent, thank you!! It's definitely more accurate this way.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making a new custom command such as
`\newcommand{\adv}[1]{ {\color{blue} #1} }`

This will reduce the effort of using it inside the tex file. To use it :
`\adv{This an advantage of the current method}`